# Delete element oh HashSet inside for

Tags: java, hashset

i want to through a HashSet with `for (MyClass edg : myHashSet)` and inside `for`, i want to delete an element for my HashSet.

```
for (MyClass edg : myHashSet)
{
    if(....)
         myHashSet.remove();
}
```

but there are an error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` how can I delete an element of a set during a parcour ?

Comment: Mehdi, if someone has answered your question it is good form to accept their answer, otherwise you'll notice people start to not answer your questions.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the modified for loop, you can use an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).  Iterators have a `remove` method that lets you remove the last element returned by `Iterator.next()`.

```
for (final java.util.Iterator<MyClass> itr = myHashSet.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    final MyClass current = itr.next();
    if(....) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i delete an element for an Iterator, it's deleted automaticaly in my Hashset ?

Comment: @user1149157 Yes.  Calling `Iterator.remove()` removes the last item returned by `Iterator.next()` from your HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

Read the javadoc:

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator method are fail-fast: if the set is modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the Iterator throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

Use an Iterator and its remove() method.

```
MyClass edg
Iterator<MyClass> hashItr = myHashSet.iterator();
while ( hashItr.hasNext() ) {
    edge = hashItr.next();
    if ( . . . )
        hashItr.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a bit of a think, been a while since I did java but another bog standard way to do this is as follows:

```
Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>(); 
Set<Person> peopleToRemove = new HashSet<Person>(); 

// fill the set of people here.
for (Person currentPerson : people) { 
    removalSet.add(currentPerson); 
} 

people.removeAll(peopleToRemove);
```

Comment: another approach is to use Iterator.remove() which avoids the normal ConcurrentModificationException an example of which can be seen above :)